# convert predicted sequence back to text in keras?

Tags: python, text, keras, sequence

I am using simple RNN model in keras to predict the categorize of simple text data .But I am unable to converted my predicted sequence in to categories

```
test_sequences = tok.texts_to_sequences(X)
test_sequences_matrix = sequence.pad_sequences(test_sequences,maxlen=max_len)
classes = model.predict(test_sequences_matrix)
```

I want to convert `classes`  in to `X` format (Sequence to text). are there any function from which i can revert back.Thanks in advance
I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41971587/how-to-convert-predicted-sequence-back-to-text-in-keras) but unable to solve to my problem

Comment: Could you add the model code as well? If it is a classification task, then `classes` would contain the probabilities of each class so you can find out the predicted classes using `.argmax` function. And then find the name of that class if you would like.